# Delete one aes from legend generated from two layes sharing common aes name

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is I want to overlay a scatter plot on top of a line plot and these two plots' color change with one variable. I only want to keep the legend for only one color. If I use `scale_colour_discrete(guide = "none")` both of them will be gone.

A reproducible example is:

```
library(reshape2)

iris2 <- melt(iris, id.var = "Species")

ggplot(iris2, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = Species)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(value < 3, "type1", "type2"))) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Species))
```

I only want to show the legend for 'Species' rather than the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setting `show_guide=FALSE` in the geom_point layer,

```
ggplot(iris2, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = Species)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(value < 3, "type1", "type2")), show_guide=FALSE) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Species)) + 
    scale_colour_discrete("Species", breaks=levels(iris2$Species))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you can get rid of only a portion of a legend when both are tied to the same aesthetic. But here's a workaround: Use a `fill` aesthetic for your points and then get rid of the legend for the `fill` aesthetic. Setting `color=NA` inside `geom_point` gets rid of the border color around each point (which is black by default). You also need to use a marker style with separate border and fill. See `?pch` for the available styles.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

iris2 = melt(iris, id.var = "Species")

ggplot(iris2, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = ifelse(value < 3, "type1", "type2")), 
             pch=21, color=NA) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Species)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! But I do think it would be better for `ggplot2` to have some options to specify where this `aes` comes from

Answer (score 0):

This too is a hack but more generalizable to other aesthetics.  It involves dumping aesthetics you don't want to make a legend you do want.  Then grabbing that legend.  Next you plot the plot you want with no legend.  Fool with the margins.  Annotate the legend you do want on the plot you want as well.

```
library(reshape2)
library(gtable)

iris2 <- melt(iris, id.var = "Species")
myplot <-ggplot(iris2, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = Species)) + 
   # geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(value < 3, "type1", "type2"))) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Species))

legend_line <- grobTree(gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(myplot)), "guide-box"))

ggplot(iris2, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = Species)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(value < 3, "type1", "type2"))) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Species)) +
    guides(color=FALSE) +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,4,1,1),"cm")) +
    annotation_custom(grob = legend_line, xmin = 4, xmax = 6.5, 
        ymin = 3.5, ymax = 4.5)
```

[image]